# Windows Service C

Tags: c, windows, winapi, service, windows-services

I have written a windows service in C but the lack of documentation on writing a service in this language means that I have a few things I need help with.

1. I want to create a config file that the service reads to get a few settings/options. I'm wondering what the best way to do this is and how to do it. The service .exe will be installed along with other files/programs at a user-specified location. The first question I have is should I keep this config file in the same directory as the service .exe or should I put it in an %appdata% folder that I create for my programs?
2. How will the service be able to find the config file. Should I store the location of the config file in the registry and hardcode the registry key into the service? Or is it possible to install the service so that it has the config file path as a default command line argument? Or should I keep my config file in the same folder as the service .exe and use the registry `HKLM/System/CurrentControlSet/Services/<servicename>/ImagePath`?
3. I have the following code:

```
void main() {
    SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY ServiceTable[2];
    ServiceTable[0].lpServiceName = L"Service Name";
    ServiceTable[0].lpServiceProc = (LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION)ServiceMain;
    ServiceTable[1].lpServiceName = NULL;
    ServiceTable[1].lpServiceProc = NULL;
    // Start the control dispatcher thread for our service
    StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(ServiceTable);
}
void ServiceMain(int argc, char** argv) { 
    //stuff here
}
```

Where does ServiceMain get its command line arguments from, is it the "Start parameters: " box under the specific service's properties? Is is possible to install it with some default parameters? Is it possible to add some in later programmatically?

1. Is it possible to make my service conditionally start when another service starts?
2. How can I install this service in production? I've been using sc from the windows sdk for development but this won't work in production. Is the only way to do this make sure microsoft .net framework is installed and then run the installutil program? My service is written without using .net framework so I would have hoped there would be a way to install the service without installing .net

Bonus Question: My service outputs to a log file. Is it possible for it to check how big the file is and delete it if it is over an arbitrary file size?

PS I don't know why the list resets to 1 & 2 after the code, it clearly says 4 and 5 in the edit box.

Comment: The arguments provided to ServiceMain are those given to StartService, as documented http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685138%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Since a service is machine-wide rather than per-user, store the configuration file under [`CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494%28VS.85%29.aspx).
2. Call [`SHGetFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) passing `CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA` to find out where that folder is.
3. The command line arguments `argv` come from the command line specified when the service was registered. This is what you can see from the service control manager.

I've not addressed the second set of questions. You should really only ask one question at a time. I do know a bit about installing services though. You certainly don't need any .net. Precisely how you should do it probably depends on which install tool you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've had a look at SHGetFolderPath but I'm not too sure how to include dll's. Would you be able to tell me where to download them from and how to include them in a visual studio 2010 project? My install tool is NSIS, should I use that to make the appdata folder? I've seen some C++ service code that installs itself the first time it is run.

Comment: Too many questions!! Don't know where DLLs come into this. Yes you use your install program to write the config file assuming information provided at install time. Services don't install when run. They can't run until installed. Chicken and egg.

Comment: lol, sorry about the questions...SHGetFolderPath requires an external library, where do I get shell32.lib/shell32.dll from? and I'm talking about the folder creation. Will windows automatically create folders when you open a file in a directory that doesn't exist? Oh and the service had a command line argument install which would then go and install it instead of calling the service control dispatcher. The .exe can be run by the installer with a cmd line argument.

Comment: shell32.dll is part of Windows. The .lib and .h ship with Visual Studio. You have to create folders if they don't exist. Yes, most services can self-install that way. Need admin rights to do so, UAC elevation before attempting to install.

Comment: How can I incorporate shell32.dll with my vs project (as i said before I dont' know what to do with dll's). The lib and h files don't seem to be included in the default includes by visual studio

Comment: You just #include the header file as described in MSDN doc for SHGetFolderPath  and you add the .lib file to your linker additional libraries in VS.

Answer (score 2):

Many services use the following Registry subkey to hold config values:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\\Parameters